The GET method is not supported for route livewire/message/header.profile. Supported methods: POST
curl "https://admin.yanachitran.in/livewire/message/header.profile" \
   -X GET \
   -H 'accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml' \
   -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd' \
   -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
   -H 'content-type: application/json' \
   -H 'content-length: 1608' \
   -H 'cookie: <CENSORED>' \
   -H 'host: admin.yanachitran.in' \
   -H 'referer: https://admin.yanachitran.in/setting/settings' \
   -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
   -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="125", "Chromium";v="125", "Not.A/Brand";v="24"' \
   -H 'x-csrf-token: <CENSORED>' \
   -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
   -H 'x-livewire: true' \
   -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"' \
   -H 'origin: https://admin.yanachitran.in' \
   -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
   -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
   -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
   -H 'priority: u=1, i';

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
i want to stop this message anyone please help me

The error message seems clear enough, you're trying to make a GET request to an endpoint which only supports POST requests. What are you trying to achieve? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

This usually happens when a Livewire message is posted, but the route isn't accessible and thus the fallback route is called, but since that's a get, you get this exception. Do you by chance have the asset_url configured? Also, what is the result when posting php artisan route:list --name=livewire? Does it show the 4 default Livewire routes?

POST       livewire/message/{name} ................. livewire.message › Livewire\Controllers › HttpConnectionHandler
GET|HEAD   livewire/preview-file/{filename} livewire.preview-file › Livewire\Controllers › FilePreviewHandler@handle
POST       livewire/upload-file ............. livewire.upload-file › Livewire\Controllers › FileUploadHandler@handle
POST       {locale}/livewire/message/{name} livewire.message-localized › Livewire\Controllers › HttpConnectionHandl…
